# Image to Text (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, image, ipad, text

How can I get the texts presented on an image ?

Description : "I am developing one application which needs to get the text presented on an Image and show the text in an another view after putting the texts in to some frames."

EDIT : From this I'm getting some Values and also the ".png" but the characters I am getting is like ASCII value or something.

`UIImage*img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_reset.png"];
    NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    NSString*str= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataObj encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    printf("Image is %s",[str UTF8String]);`

Any tutorial/link/solution would be very helpful.

Thank You !

Comment: Are you seriously trying to do OCR this way?

Comment: @Till - Can you help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might get solution from following link:
[Is there any iphone Class that converts images to text format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790466/is-there-any-iphone-class-that-converts-images-to-text-format/4815534#4815534)

Comment: Thanks Dimple , Some more elaborated thing will help me out as I am a beginner. :)

Comment: This might help you along with video http://robertcarlsen.net/2009/12/06/ocr-on-iphone-demo-1043

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't understand the question clearly, but I think you are referring to OCR.
One of the main open-source lib for this is: [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)

Some one has ported this lib for ios. You can get the code from: https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR/

Comment: @Akshay, It is actually working for me but with a crash some times.

Comment: May be. Will try it out again and let you know Vikram.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the string

```
UIImage*img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_reset.png"];
NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img); 
NSString*str= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataObj encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];        
NSLog("Image is %@",str);
```

If you still dont get it change the encoding

Comment: It doesn't fill all my requirements but Thanks for the response. :)